# Entity Framework Core for temporary command add MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

how to change default connection string by adding MultipleActiveResultSets=True property just for single command at the time of command creation

> var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()

Answer (score 0):

before Open the Dbconnection,you could set the dbconnecton and after the connection is closed,you could Set back to the default connectionstring

```
var dbconnection = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();            
var defaultconstr = dbconnection.ConnectionString;            
            
            using (var command1 = dbconnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command1.Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AnotherDbContext-ace411ee-9d25-458a-a4f2-1c7d4f454da5;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
                command1.Connection.Open();
                command1.CommandText = "insert into MenuItem(Name,Slug) values('nn','ss')";
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command1.Connection.Close();
                command1.Connection.ConnectionString = defaultconstr;
                command1.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: I tried but found response, cannot change connection string before GetDbConnection

Comment: Could you show how you tried? I inserted the two columns into the db successfully and in next dbcommand,the connection string was the default conect string